# Generate Graphs in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel

Is it possible to code into Excel via Python and produce graphs in specific Excel formatting? There is a specific and customized formatting for the graphs and plots that I need to use. I did all the data cleansing and analysis in Python and would like to continue and finish all the work in one run of the program, instead of transferring over to excel and trying to figure out the automation process - I have something like 35 dataframes (all in the same format and labeling) that each will produce around 50 graphs and plots.

I am familiar with reading and writing to and from excel files but not sure if it is possible to do what I am looking for.

Thanks and please let me know if any further clarification is needed!

Comment: Look into doing this with openpyxl. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely possible since I have recently complete one of the task using below libraries.

1. Reading and Writing from and to excel -> Pandas
2. Visualizing the data into your python editor -> Matplotlib
3. Visualizing the data into your excel sheet -> xlswriter charts

Below are some of the links that will help you to get a brief view.

[xlswriter charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html)
[matplotlib.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

Hope that answers your question.